# How to grab output from evaluating input cells in a generated notebook

Tags: front-end

The notebook expression resulting from ...

```
nb = CreateDocument[ExpressionCell[Defer@Random[], "Input"]];
FrontEndTokenExecute[nb, "EvaluateNotebook"];
NotebookGet@nb
```

does *not* include the output of `Random[]` as I might have expected from the `FrontEndTokenExecute` command. Instead `NotebookGet@nb` acts as if `FrontEndTokenExecute` was *not* evaluated despite its execution in the frontend?

I guess this is due to the separation/communication between the frontend and the kernel but can output from evaluations in a generated notebook be grabbed in a single kernel call?

See answer below:

Comment: I do get a new notebook with a random number in it...

Comment: Ron I get the output as well. OS X 10.6.8 with V8.0.4.

Comment: @Sjoerd & Mike The random number appears in the generated notebook itself but on my machine the expression ``NotebookGet@nb`` returns instead ``Notebook[{Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{"Random", "[", "]"}]], "Input"]}, 
 WindowSize -> {740, 752}, 
 WindowMargins -> {{350, Automatic}, {Automatic, 50}}, 
 FrontEndVersion -> 
  "8.0 for Mac OS X x86 (32-bit, 64-bit Kernel) (October 5, 2011)", 
 StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]``?

Comment: If you execute `NotebookGet@nb` in separate cell you get you expected output (perhaps confirming your guess?)

Comment: ok I see what you mean.

Comment: @kguler yes confirming my guess but as per solution below maybe staying in the kernel is more reliable anyway.

Comment: @Ronald, nice solution.

Answer (score 6):

It turns out that instead of `FrontEndTokenExecute[nb, "EvaluateNotebook"]` the seemingly equivalent `NotebookEvaluate[nb, InsertResults -> True]` *does* exhibit the expected behaviour which is good as this function seems neater anyway (and has a few more options).

```
nb = CreateDocument[ExpressionCell[Defer@Random[], "Input"]];
NotebookEvaluate[nb, InsertResults -> True];
NotebookGet@nb
```